# Nunit-console - what is expected in .csproj file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono, nunit, csproj

I'm currently doing some tests with C# (using Mono and NUnit, all on OS X but it's supposed to run on Travis later). I did not install Visual studio and managed to get a "working" .csproj file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Compile">
  <Target Name="Compile">
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" References="@(Reference)" TargetType="Library" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
    <Exec Command="nunit-console nunit.csproj" />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Include="../csharp/class/CoffeeMachine.cs" />
     <Compile Include="tests/Actionwords.cs" />
     <Compile Include="tests/ProjectTest.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Compilation works fine but I can't execute the tests, I get the following error:

```
╰─$ nunit-console nunit.csproj
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 14.3.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( 4.2.0 (Stable 4.2.0.179/a224653 Tue Oct  6 11:27:49 PDT 2015) )

Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: Invalid project file format: nunit.csproj ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject.LoadMSBuildProject (System.String projectDirectory, System.Xml.XmlDocument doc) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 257
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject.LoadProject (System.String projectDirectory, System.Xml.XmlDocument doc) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 210
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject.Load () in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 184
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject.ThrowInvalidFormat (System.String projectPath, System.Exception e) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 307
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject.Load () in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 197
   at NUnit.Util.VSProject..ctor (System.String projectPath) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/VSProject.cs:line 56
   at NUnit.Util.NUnitProject.FromVSProject (System.String vsProjectPath) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/NUnitProject.cs:line 234
   at NUnit.Util.NUnitProject.LoadProject (System.String path) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ClientUtilities/util/NUnitProject.cs:line 161
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.MakeRunnerFromCommandLine (NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleOptions options) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ConsoleRunner/nunit-console/ConsoleUi.cs:line 214
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute (NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleOptions options) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ConsoleRunner/nunit-console/ConsoleUi.cs:line 58
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main (System.String[] args) in /private/tmp/mono20151006-19632-tqpley/mono-4.2.0/mcs/nunit24/ConsoleRunner/nunit-console/Runner.cs:line 63
```

Note: if I execute `nunit-console hiptest.publisher.samples.dll` it works like a charm.

My guess is that NUnit expects the .csproj file to tell what is the test target. I tried to add an AssemblyName group under a PropertyGroup but it did not make any difference.

And the big problem is that I can't find any doc on what is expected from the .csproj content by Nunit (I mainly find examples where everything is done via VS or using MSBuild community tasks, which sounds really nice but apparently does not play nice with my environment (Mono, OS X and a different NUnit package than the one released with Mono (not on that project, on another one using Specflow but if I can fix it for this one it should be fixed for the second one)).

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using NUnit console 2.4.x and 3.x with `.csproj` files, it expects a valid and fairly complete MSBuild/xbuild project to determine the assembly name, dir location, and namespace that it will test in the Library-based project (Exe-based projects are possible if you have defined the proper entry point). In this example I used NUnit 2.4.x and 3.x **console** as there are execution differences but the same `.csproj` is being used so if you are using MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio the IDE's built-in NUnit 2.4.x test pad will also work. Also I would *assume* you would also use Mono's `xbuild` to build your project on Travis so a complete `.csproj` will be needed.

**NUnit 3.0 console (Install via nuget):**

```
mono $(MTOOLS)/nunit3-console.exe  nunit-lib/nunit-lib.csproj --config=Debug

NUnit Console Runner 3.0.5797 
Copyright (C) 2015 Charlie Poole

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: MacOSX 15.0.0.0 
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020

Test Files
    nunit-lib/nunit-lib.csproj

Errors and Failures

1) Failed : nunitlib.Test.TestCase
  Expected string length 8 but was 5. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "Overflow"
  But was:  "Stack"
  -----------^
at nunitlib.Test.TestCase () in <filename unknown>:line 0

Test Run Summary
    Overall result: Failed
   Tests run: 1, Passed: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 1, Inconclusive: 0
     Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Explicit: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2015-11-20 12:36:28Z
    End time: 2015-11-20 12:36:28Z
    Duration: 0.132 seconds
```

**NUnit 2.4.8 (installed via Mono):**

**NOTE**: NUnit console 2.4.x is `broken` due a hard-coded Windows-style Directory Separator when parsing `.csproj` files and creating the expected CIL/assembly location, use `MONO_IOMAP` to work around it. This is not a issue in 3.0.

**NUnit Console 2.4.x w/o MONO_IOMAP:**

```
nunit-console nunit-lib/nunit-lib.csproj -config=Debug
~~~~
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory "/Users/sushi/code/XamTests/nunit-lib/nunit-lib/bin\Debug" not found.
~~~~
```

**NUnit Console 2.4.x with MONO_IOMAP:**

```
MONO_IOMAP=all nunit-console nunit-lib/nunit-lib.csproj -config=Debug

NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 15.0.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( 4.2.1 (explicit/8862921 Thu Oct 29 17:09:16 EDT 2015) )

.F
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Not run: 0, Time: 0.115 seconds

Test Case Failures:
1) nunitlib.Test.TestCase :   Expected string length 8 but was 5. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "Overflow"
  But was:  "Stack"
  -----------^
```

**.csproj example used in for example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{944946CD-39B2-4A16-A8A8-9F70F0450506}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>nunitlib</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>nunit-lib</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Test.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```